# ¿cómo puedo establecer conexión con postgresql con angular 8?

Tags: angular, angular8

Tengo esto: 
Antes de esto ya he hecho npm install pg pero ya he intentado de todo hasta he borrado el proyecto como 3 veces y me vuelve a dar los mismo.

```
  private listaUsuarios() {
    const { Client } = require('pg');
    const connectionData = {
      user: 'ejemplouser',
      host: 'ejemplohost',
      database: 'ejemploDB',
      password: 'clavesecreta',
      port: 5432,
    };
    const client = new Client(connectionData);
  }
```

Pero me devuelve un error

> error TS2591: Cannot find name 'require'. Do you need to install type definitions for node?

Answer (score 2):

No es culpa de Angular ni de PG. Ese error te lo da TypeScript, que no tiene por sí mismo la sintaxis para hacer `require`. Esa sintaxis, usualmente conocida como `CommonJS` **y propia de Node**, tampoco está en el browser sino que depende de librerías complementarias o una fase de build.

Acerca de lo que puse en negrita, Typescript te está indicando lo que necesitas: las definiciones de tipos para Node. (Typescript es obsesivo con los tipos pero esa es su virtud). Así que hazle caso e instálalos:

```
npm i -D @types/node
```

aunque personalmente prefiero

```
yarn add -D @types/node
```

Hay más de una manera de arreglarlo, sólo sugiero la que he usado. [En este hilo comentan de al menos 4 maneras](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31173738/typescript-getting-error-ts2304-cannot-find-name-require) que no he probado.

Comment: Muchas gracias, lo voy a probar cuando vuelva a ponerme con este código. Saludos.